# Email sending via cron, pubsub

Tags: javascript, typescript, cron

I get stuck with creating a new trigger to send only one email the next day, after changing the status in orders to 'DELIVERED', that is, create a query in the sendStatusEmails trigger that retrieves orders by status and id. Who can help with this problem or give an example?

Here's cron dailyEmails.js

```
module.exports = functions.pubsub
.schedule("0 0 12 * *")
.timeZone("")
.onRun(async () => {
 await checkUnsentOrders();
 await gameMailUnsentOrders();
 await sendStatusEmails();

 ]);
});
```

example of trigger gameMailUnsentOrders.js

```
const processGamerStatusReminderEmail = async (gamerOrders: OrderData[]) => {
  const firstOrder = _.head(gamerOrders);
  const gamerName = firstOrder
    ? firstOrder.gamerName
      ? firstOrder.gamerName
      : ""
    : "";
  const gamerId = firstOrder
    ? firstGameOrder.gamerId
      ? firstGameOrder.gamerId
      : ""
    : "";
  const gamerData = await (await gamer.doc(gamerId).get()).data();
  const gamerReminderEmail = gamerData.reminderEmail;
  if (gamerReminderEmail === "" || !gamerReminderEmail) {
    console.log(
      ` ${gamerName} email is not finded`
    );
    return;
  }
  let rows = gamerOrders
    .map(
      (doc: OrderData) =>
        `...`
    )
  let view = `<strong>Status: </strong> ${status}(
                `;
  return await sentGameHtmlEmail(
    gamerReminderEmail
  );
};
module.exports = async () => {
    const startDate = startOfDate();
    const endDate = endOfDate();
    const dateBefore = dateBeforeGameDay();
    const finalizedStatusDayBefore = [
      ...finalisedOrdersStatusIds,
             constants.DELIVERED.id,
 
    ];
    let listGameOrders = await getGameOrdersMailing(startDate, endDate);
    let ordersStatus = listGameOrders.filter((gameOrder) => {
      const gameDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(gameOrder.gamePDate)
      .toJSDate();
      if (dateBefore.getDay() === gameDate.getDay()) {
        return !finalizedStatusDayBefore.includes(gameOrder.gameStatus.id);
      }
      return !finalisedOrdersStatusIds.includes(gameOrder.gameStatus.id);
    });
    let orderedByGamerId = _.orderBy(
      ordersStatus.map((order) => order),
      "gamerId"
    );
    return await Promise.all(
      _.map(orderedByGamerId, (gameOrders: OrderData[]) => {
        return processGamerReminderEmail(gameOrders);
      })
    );
  };
```